# No such file or directory error in python

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, filepath

In my python study,I meet a problem like this:

```
 File "wfdbtools.py", line 418, in _getheaderlines
 all_lines = open(hfile, 'r').readlines()

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\liujiankang\\Desktop\\\xe7\xa8\x8b\xe5\xba\x8f-1\\datafile\x03908522m\x03908522m_ECG.txt.hea'
```

the Corresponding code:

```
def check_qrs_detection():
from wfdbtools import rdsamp, rdann
import subprocess
test_record = 'C:\Users\liujiankang\Desktop\程序-1\datafile\3908522m\3908522m_ECG.txt'
qrslead = 2

data, info = rdsamp(test_record)

qrsdetector = QRSDetector(data, info['samp_freq'])

qrspeaks = qrsdetector.qrs_detect(qrslead)
print 'Found %s QRS complexes' %(len(qrspeaks))
qrsdetector.write_ann(os.path.abspath(test_record) + '.test')

ref_qrs = rdann(os.path.abspath(test_record), 'atr')
print ref_qrs.shape
print qrspeaks[:10]
print ref_qrs[:10, :1]
sigdata = data[:, qrslead]
pylab.plot(sigdata)
for r in qrspeaks:
    pylab.plot(r, sigdata[r], 'xr')
for r in ref_qrs[:, 1]:
    pylab.plot(r*info['samp_freq'], sigdata[r*info['samp_freq']], 'ob')
pylab.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
check_qrs_detection()
test()
```

Since the code is copied from someone else,the original path which I suspected is follows:

```
test_record = '../samples/format212/100'`
```

What may be the problem?Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is that `test_record` has unicode characters but you did not declare it as a unicode string. In fact, its got a serialization of unicode, maybe utf-8 maybe some windows code page, I don't know. As a minimum set it up as a unicode string `test_record = u'C:\Users\liujiankang\Desktop\程序-1\datafile\3908522m\3908522m_ECG.txt'`. But unless you have some compelling reason to use python 2.x, move to python 3. Its unicode handling is much better.

Comment: I can't test the solution on my machine... let me know if it works!

Comment: I  am sorry for network delay,the  interpretation is like this:# Read in the data from 0 to 10 seconds
    >> data, info = rdsamp(record, 0, 10)
    
    # returned data is an array. The columns are time(samples),
    # time(seconds), signal1, signal2

Comment: I'm not sure what that comment means! should it be in a code block in the question for easier reading? Anyway, you still need to attend to those non-english characters in the filename: 程序. Although they look correct on your screen, its really `\xe7\xa8\x8b\xe5\xba\x8f` in the string. You need to make that a unicode string (the u on front). If you are reading the file from some other source, you need to do `filename.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: I am sorry for that.I am newer here,and I am  learning how to post the question in a better way.